# Smooth moving nodes implementation in a visual dictionary

Tags: html5-canvas

**Background information:** 
I have a assessment in a few weeks for an extra program I follow besides my study. My idea was to make a interactive '**wordspider**' myself with 'custom' words about the extra program. I've looked up the web and I came across some cool sites showing several neat functionalities. Please have a look at yourself at the websites below. What catches my eye is the **smoothness of all the 'nodes'** (words, dots). When you move one node, the position of another node nearby is also affected. The effect is similar like rubber bands.

**My question:** 
And so my question is: how did they implemented the smooth effect that the position of every node is dependent of every other node?

**What I did myself:**

1. I tried to save the whole page (<kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) and tried to open it. It
   didn't worked out very well... The nodes aren't moving at all.
2. Send an email to the visualthesaurus asking this same question I'm asking here, they currently not providing an api and they won't give me the source code (what a surprise).
3. With the inspector looked up

**Website links:** 
http://visuwords.com/stack 
https://www.visualthesaurus.com/

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you have the option to use [D3JS](https://d3js.org/) (which is based in SVG--not html5 Canvas), then you can almost effortlessly create a [force layout](http://bl.ocks.org/ccmcc/5182685) to display your word-spider. With a little more manual labor you can get html5 canvas to display a [force directed layout](https://sebhtml.github.io/force-graph/)

Comment: Thank you so much @markE for your comment, I think the example of the force directed layout will do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The best answer came from @markE thanks, the following came the most close:
http://sebhtml.github.io/force-graph/